# Null set vs Measure zero set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

In the context of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is null set the same thing as a set of measure zero?

I understand that null set implies measure zero, not sure about the other direction.

Update: By null set I mean https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set a set that can be covered by a countable union of intervals(balls)  of arbitrarily small total length.

To be precise: Is a set with measure zero coverable by countable union of balls of arbitrarily small total length?

Comment: What is your definition of a null set? Usually the term null set means a set of measure zero.

Comment: I have never seen a distinction.

Comment: For signed measures they are different.

Comment: @carmichael561 By null set I mean it can be covered by countable union of balls of arbitrary small total measure.

Comment: @yoyostein so by definition you give it means Lebesgue measure of the set is 0.

Comment: How about the converse: if the Lebesgue measure is zero, can it be covered by balls with arbitrary small total length?

Comment: I would advise NOT using the term "null set", since it's often used by some authors to mean the empty set, and it's also sometimes used to mean variously defined notions of sets being small enough to be "removable" in interpolation theory, harmonic analysis, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is a set with measure zero coverable by countable union of balls of arbitrarily small total length?

Yes. This follows from the fact that the Lebesgue measure is constructed using a generator of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (say the set of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$) using Caratheodory's Extension Theorem.

In particular, if we denote $\mu((a,b)) = b-a$ for any open interval $(a,b)$, we can define for any $A\subset\mathbb{R}$

$$\lambda^*(A) =\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n): \text{each $A_n$ an open interval, $A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n, $}\right\}.$$

This $\lambda^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure. If $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure then any measurable set satisfies $\lambda(A) = \lambda^*(A)$. The result then follows by the definition of the infimum.