# What is an m-null set?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

On the 'Properties' section of the [Wikipedia page of Null set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set#Properties), it says:

> Together, these facts show that the m-null sets of X form a sigma-ideal on X.

I looked for a definition of 'm-null set' on that same page, but I did not find it. I also browsed MathSE, but I only found the post " [Null set vs Measure zero set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780458/null-set-vs-measure-zero-set) " , which does not answer my question.

What is the meaning of 'm-null set' ?

Comment: Subset of a set which has measure 0 with respect to the measure $m$ I would imagine. Edit: according to Wikipedia, it's a measurable set with measure 0 with respect to $m$.

Comment: @jgon thank you for the interest! You mentioned Wikipedia; do you have a link please?

Comment: what I meant is I was looking at the wiki article you linked. The construct $X$-adjective is very common where $X$ is a mathematical object, and the adjective is one whose definition refers to some other mathematical object than the one described. The construct is used to provide context for that other mathematical object. Perhaps the most common examples of this in my experience are $R$-module, and $k$-vector space. The construction can also be used with nouns whose definitions refer to another object, for example $k$-basis.

Comment: Anyway, here $m$ is a measure, and $m$-null means null with respect to the measure $m$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In all other cases, that article refers to the measure as $\mu $ . Why the need to suddenly stop using $\mu $ and change it for $m$ ?

Comment: Not sure why they switched from $\mu$ to $m$ there. Perhaps it's an artifact of Wikipedia being a compilation of many writers' work. $m$ is certainly a common name for a measure as well.

Comment: @jgon Got it, thank you! Would you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Feel free to accept HennoBrandsma's answer, which I think is pretty good. I've been replying on mobile anyway, so I can't write an answer of appropriate quality right now.

Comment: @jgon got it, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article would have been a bit better if it had used $\mu$-null set instead, because it introduces a measure $\mu$ on the space $X$ in the beginning. What is meant is a null set w.r.t. some measure $m$ (or better: $\mu$). It can help if there are several measures under discussion to add  the $\mu$- or ($m$-) prefix to "null sets" to avoid confusion. It *is* good to realise that saying *null set* means implicitly that there must be an unambiguous measure (from context) we are using to define the notion. E.g. in the context of sets of real numbers it probably means Lebesgue-null set.